# Float Doesn't Work In IE6

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer-6

I have a problem with float in Internet Explorer 6.

The problem is that ie6 not do the float, not put the column next to other column

This is the HTML code:

```
<div id="contingut">
    <div id="col_esq">
        <div class="menu">
            ... 
        </div>
        <div class="25anys"> <img src="img/25_anys.png"  /></div>
    </div>
    <div id="col_dreta"> ....</div>
</div>
```

and CSS code:

```
#col_esq{
    display: inline;
    width:230px;
    float:left;

}

#col_dreta{
    float:left;
    width:675px;
    height:100%;
    display: inline;
}
```

The URL to visit the site is: http://abs.marcmorales.es/index.php?s=5&i=1

Comment: -1 "I have a problem with Float in Internet Explorer 6" is not a question. Can you please describe exactly what the issue is, so that we at least have some idea what we're looking for when we click your link?

Comment: The problem is that ie6 not do the float, not put the column next to other column

Comment: floats are not the problem. IE6 IS the problem.

Answer (score 1):

Try playing with the width (lowering it) because if the parent got any margins IE bugs and gives the children also the same margin. Sometime `position relative` fixes problems in IE.

Also why are they `display inline` and not `display block`?

Comment: I prove if runs with display inline